# CSS Bootstrap Navigation min-width: 992px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this bootstrap navigation:

```
<div id="navigation-sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper is-sticky" style="height: 125px;"><nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navigation" style="position: fixed; top: 0px;">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle toggled" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </button>
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.jpg"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/example.jpg"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/example2.jpg"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav></div>
```

What I am trying to do is when my screen is:

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
}
```

is have the navigation like so: logo and navbar-right above the menu and centered.....how would I accomplish this I have been trying to play with the floats, but that hasnt really been working out....any suggestions?

Comment: nav, .navbar, .navbar-nav has 'FLOAT:LEFT;' value. This must be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your media query:

```
.navbar-brand   {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
  }
```

Comment: Did you add the above within the media query?? And can you please post a jsfiddle of what you have so I can check what's wrong